# TIbco EMS Veritas to Redhat GFS2

Tags: redhat, tibco, ems

We are deploying Tibco EMS with Redhat GFS2.I want to understand if GFS2 supports HA/DR as with Veritas. Capabilities like process HA and ip remapping from Active to Standby at the time of failover without data loss.

If GFS2 does not support this can we leverage VMware suite capabilities for tibco ems deployed on physical servers?

Answer (score 0):

The EMS with GFS2 combined will permit you to ensure High Availability on your EMS Instances.
Good competencies are required to setup the GFS2 correctly. 
TIBCO supports GFS2 for EMS.